# C++ string library, to get a string by removing the integers in it

Tags: c++, string, int

I've a string like "Hello world 1 2 3" and I want to get a string like "Hello World". Do you know any function for it?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Do you want to exclude numbers, do you want strings like "S123ABC" as well, etc...

Comment: Loop 0-9, replacing instances of each with an empty string. In your example, you'd probably want to trim off leading/trailing whitespace as well.

Answer (score 3):

As a first approximation, assuming you want all digits removed and the result put into a new string, I'd start with something like this:

```
std::remove_copy_if(your_string.begin(), your_string.end(), 
                    std::back_inserter(new_string),
                    [](unsigned char ch) { return isdigit(ch); });
```

Comment: I think you can even avoid the lambda and just pass `isdigit` as unary predicate.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: You can, *but* on implementations where `char` is signed (which is most) it will give UB when you pass a character whose value is negative.

Comment: Just checked the C standard and it's as you said... WTF were they thinking? (although, arguably TRWTF is that `char` typically is signed)

Comment: @MatteoItalia: at least by the time the committee got involved, I suspect most of what they were thinking was that they couldn't really fix the situation, so about the best they could do was make requirements explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all digits from string

```
string x
x.erase(
  std::remove_if(x.begin(), x.end(), &isdigit), 
  x.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done using the `std::ctype<char>` facet to classify alphanumeric including whitespace characters:

```
#include <locale>
#include <functional>

template <class charT = char>
bool digit_removal(charT c, std::locale loc)
{
    return std::use_facet<std::ctype<charT>>(loc).is(
        std::ctype_base::digit, c);
}

int main()
{
    std::string var = "Hello 123";
    var.erase(
        std::remove_if(var.begin(), var.end(),
          std::bind(&digit_removal<char>, std::placeholders::_1, std::locale())),
    var.end());


    std::cout << var; // "Hello "
}
```

Comment: If you go this route (and I usually do), you'll want to extract the facet just once, rather than each call do the function.  (This is trivial if you use a functional object, rather than a function.)

Comment: No offense, but this is a perfect example of how C++ tends to overcomplicate and hyperverbosize simple things. C++ locale library+functors+bind=big unreadable mess.

Comment: @MatteoItalia The only thing I see as an overkill is the `bind` part. That part can be shortened.

Comment: Don't worry, I think that your code is exactly how the standard library is meant to be used, the problem in facts IMO is in the standard library. You shouldn't need this mess to remove digits from a string (and in facts, removing all the "C++ locales" part removes most of the cruft); what disturbs me is not that in Python this would be a one-liner, but that in *C* it would be way shorter and, most importantly, much more understandable.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I know what you mean. This language overwhelmed me back when I was just coming from javascript. lol

Comment: @MatteoItalia The problem is that it's not a simple thing; some of the things `ctype` tries to do (like `tolower`) are practically impossible, since there is no one to one mapping of upper case to lower.  And while C++ complicates it in some ways, it does avoid the usual cause of errors in the C version---at least the C++ versions of `isdigit` can be called with a `char`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: the `isdigit`/`char` thing is a bug that makes that function awkward, not really a design choice; and my complaint is mostly of API, not of functionality. As often happens in C++-land they tried to put together a library that could do anything (a locale can contain arbitrary, user-extendable facets), which results in a bloated interface (`std::use_facet<std::ctype<charT>>(loc).is(std::ctype_base::digit, c);` to check if a `char` is a digit? are you kidding me?), without shortcuts for common usage, poor vendor support and virtually no actual use in the real world.

Comment: @MatteoItalia The interface could be better, but in practice, you've soon got it wrapped in functional objects (which can be used with `std::find_if`, etc.).  And in practice, you have to wrap the functions in `<ctype.h>` as well, since you _will_ want to use them with iterators whose `value_type` is `char`.  So the only difference is in the wrappers.  And the fact that with `<locale>`, you can use the locale that you need, _without_ dealing with the global locale.